# Bind database to Collection c#

Tags: c#, .net, database, collections, binding

I am developing a data intensive app in C# and need some advice on the best method to manage my data. My application will use a number of related tables with a lot of movement backwards and forwards between the app and the database.

My question is, what method would be best to handle data? All of my data fields are controlled within their own classes and collections, so hence, the question is really more of a case of what is the best method to bind my collections and objects to the database.

Should I manually create my own SQL connections / SQL Insert / Update queries, or is there another way to do this? For instance is it possible in Visual Studio to easily create a strongly typed data layer that will automatically look after Inserts / Updates / Deletes etc?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you looked into Entity Framework and Fluent API?

Comment: it sound like EF code first

Comment: @DanOrlovsky Yes, just had a look and test of EF, albeit a slight learning curve all seems well. I've also noticed I can use DataSet / DataAdaptors which are also strongly typed. Any advice on which method would be best? My experience is that Datasets are old school now and EF is the way forward?

Comment: I will risk a downvote in order to try and point you in the right direction - it just won't be very organized in Comment form, however, this question is pretty broad and probably belongs in another part of SE.  Stand by, I'm typing it up now.

Answer (score 1):

**Q. For instance is it possible in Visual Studio to easily create a strongly typed data layer that will automatically look after Inserts / Updates / Deletes etc?**

Entity Framework sounds like something you're looking for.  There is, of course, some setup involved.  With most web projects, Entity Framework is automatically added, and if not you can always add it via NuGet package manager.

EntityFramework binds your models to a Database through the DbContext object, and Code First will even generate a database if one does not exist based on your models (if one does exist and the models change, you might have to migrate: [More reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)).  I will be taking that approach (you can later change the following code to a connection string to a live DB).

First, you need to tell your application what database to use (whether it exists or not), and this can be done in the Web.Config file (not the only approach).

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
  ....
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DATABASENAME.mdf;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**NOTE** - this connection string will only work in VS2015.  For previous versions, use:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DATABASENAME.mdf
```

[More reading on configuring Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606)

Now, we can use "ConnectionStringName" to connect our context.

The Context class will have to inherit from the DbContext object, and we will pass this connection string name to the base constructor (DbContext exists in the System.Data.Entity namespace).  I will use two generic models that look identical (ModelA ModelB) --

**ModelA and ModelB**

```
using System.ComponentModels.DataAnnotations;

public class ModelA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="You need to enter a name!")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**NOTE** - I'm using DataAnnotations (Required, StringLength) - these are really cool and can be very useful when implementing CRUD operations on your model.
ALSO -- Entity Framework will automatically make properties that are named: Id (or any case form) or ModelNameId the primary key.  There are ways to override this.

[More reading on DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can even create your models with relationships in mind.  If ModelA will have a one-to-many relationship with ModelB, you can reflect this relationship in code:

`public virtual ICollection<ModelB> ModelBs {get; set;}`

[More reading on creating relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)

We will now map your models to tables using the DbSet collection.  Here's how that looks:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using YourProject.Data.Models;

namespace YourProject.Data.DAL
{
    public class YourContext : DbContext
    {
        public YourContext() : base("ConnectionStringName")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ModelA> ModelAs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ModelB> ModelBs { get; set; }

    }
}
```

[Database Initialization Strategies](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) - for seeding your database with data on creation.

[More reading on configuring the context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx)

I will never be able to detail everything you can do - but here are a few short examples:

**Q. What does all this do?**

You now have a strongly-typed object connected to your database.  It's as simple as creating a new Context object:

```
YourContext yourContext = new YourContext();
```

Retrieving a whole table is as easy as:

```
IEnumerable<ModelA> modelAs = yourContext.ModelAs;
```

or finding a row by Id

`ModelB modelB = yourContext.ModelBs.Find(id);`

Say you grabbed modelB and want to update it.  It's as easy as:

```
modelB.Name = "Here's the new name";
yourContext.Entry(modelB).State = EntityState.Modified;
yourContext.SaveChanges();
```

Adding:

```
yourContext.ModelAs.Add(newModel);
```

Removing:

```
yourContext.ModelBs.Remove(modelB);
```

**REMEMBER** Add/Update/Delete methods will ALL require a call to SaveChanges(); from the Context.  Otherwise they will be discarded.

Of course, this is probably the most basic rundown of Entity Framework available.  To see more of it in action check out these tutorials:

[WebForms with Entity Framework - Wingtip Toys](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview)

[MVC with Entity Framework - Contoso University](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Hope this may be of assistance for someone.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put together. FYI it's a native desktop application I'm writing. My main concern is that my software is in it's infancy stage of development and my prior experience of a data intensive app (ten years ago in .NET 2.0) was that any structural changes in the data structure proved to be a nightmare to update in my code. Reading the above and a few other articles, it would seem that EF is the way forward. Cheers

Comment: @glenn - this will work on a native desktop app as well.  Less the web.config part - but use the app.config